# Extracting ROI from images using Python

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I'm trying to remove the background of an image. I've had little luck using the method described here (Get boundary from canny edges and remove the background of an image), but I have been able to successfully remove the background when the background of the image is white or light colored ("123456789.jpg"). The problem is that this method cannot remove the background of an image when the background color is black or dark ("12345678.jpg"). Heres my code I'm running：

> [123456789.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HY0lA.jpg)
> [123456789success.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iy68f.jpg)
> [12345678.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLS97.jpg)
> [12345678fail.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jddVY.jpg)

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
image = cv2.imread("123456789.jpg")
original = image.copy()
mask = np.zeros(image.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5,5))
opening = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel, iterations=3)
cnts = cv2.findContours(opening, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
cnts = sorted(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)
for c in cnts:
    cv2.drawContours(mask, [c], -1, (255,255,255), -1)
    break
close = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel, iterations=4)
close = cv2.cvtColor(close, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
result = cv2.bitwise_and(original, original, mask=close)
result[close==0] = (0,0,0)
cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Therefore, I want to improve my method so that I can remove the black background of the image to obtain ROI.

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: Rather than converting to grayscale, threshold on your object color using cv2.inRange() and then apply some morphology to clean it up before getting the contour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to process your images in Python/OpenCV is to convert to HSV and threshold etc on the saturation channel, since your background seems to be grayscale and your center object is color.

- Read the input
- Convert to HSV and extract the saturation channel
- Threshold the saturation channel
- Apply morphology close to fill in the holes
- Remove any border seen in this image due to a faint border in the input
- Find contours and extract the largest one
- Draw this contour on a copy of the input as the result
- Save the results

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read the input
img = cv2.imread('light.jpg')
#img = cv2.imread('dark.jpg')
hh, ww = img.shape[:2]

# convert to HSV and extract the saturation channel
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
sat = hsv[:,:,1]

# threshold
thresh = cv2.threshold(sat, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# apply morphology close 
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT , (21,21))
morph = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

# remove border detected from (second) input
bias = 10
morph = morph[bias:hh-bias, bias:ww-bias]
morph = cv2.copyMakeBorder(morph, bias,bias,bias,bias, borderType=cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, value=(0,0,0))

# get largest contour and draw it on input
result = img.copy()
contours = cv2.findContours(morph, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]
big_contour = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)
cv2.drawContours(result, [big_contour], 0, (0,255,0), 2)

# save results
cv2.imwrite('light_contour.jpg', result)
#cv2.imwrite('dark_contour.jpg', result)

# show results
cv2.imshow('sat', sat)
cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('morph', morph)
cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Input 1(light background):

[image]

Result 1:

[image]

Input 2(dark background):

[image]

Result 2:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are automatically determining the threshold using OTSU (`cv2.THRESH_OTSU`) and perform more morphological operations. You are also selecting the largest contour as the mask, which can be beneficial if you have complex shapes in the foreground and want to ensure that the largest part is retained. But this is not the case in your example.

Updated code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load the image
image = cv2.imread("123456789.jpg")
original = image.copy()

# Convert the image to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Threshold the grayscale image to separate the foreground from the dark background
_, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 40, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

# Find contours in the thresholded image
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# Create a mask to store the foreground region
mask = np.zeros_like(image)

# Iterate through the contours and draw them on the mask
for contour in contours:
    cv2.drawContours(mask, [contour], -1, (255, 255, 255), -1)

# Bitwise AND the original image and the mask to extract the foreground
result = cv2.bitwise_and(original, mask)

# Show the result
cv2.imshow('Result', result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

In this code, I using a lower threshold value (40 in this case) to create a binary mask that separates the dark background from the foreground. I then find contours in the binary mask, create a mask to store the foreground region and draw the contours on this mask. Then, I am using a bitwise AND operation to extract the foreground from the original image using the mask.

This code is giving the desired image for both your images and is also simpler.

**Note, you should adjust the threshold value (`40` in this case) as needed to achieve the best results for your specific images. This method should work well for images with dark backgrounds.**

Also, if you are new to open-cv or do want to do this on scale, you can also check out some AI tools that do smart cropping such as [Smart Image Crop API](https://apilayer.com/marketplace/smart_crop-api) or [Cloudinary's Imagga crop](https://cloudinary.com/blog/beyond_face_detection_smart_cropping_in_the_cloud_using_imagga_and_cloudinary) plugin.

Hope this helps.